# outputting image back to matlab Mex

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, image-processing, mex

I am trying to output an image from my mex file back to my matlab file, but when i  open it in matlab it is not correct.

The output image withing the mex file is correct

I have tried switching the orientation of the mwSize as well as swapping `i` and `j` in `new_img.at<int>(j, i)`;

```
Mat image = imread(mxArrayToString(prhs[0]));
Mat new_img(H,W, image.type(), Scalar(0));
// some operations on new_img
imshow( "gmm image", image ); //shows the original image
imshow( "gmm1 image", new_img ); //shows the output image
waitKey( 200 );  //both images are the same size as desired

mwSize nd = 2;
mwSize dims[] = {W, H};

plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericArray(nd, dims, mxUINT8_CLASS, mxREAL);
if(plhs == NULL) {
  mexErrMsgTxt("Could not create mxArray.\n");     
}     
char* outMat = (char*) mxGetData( plhs[0]);

for (int i= 0; i < H; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < W; j++)
  {       
    outMat[i +j*image.rows] = new_img.at<int>(j, i);       
  }
}
```

this is in the mat file

```
gmmMask = GmmMex2(imgName,rect);
imshow(gmmMask); % not the same as the output image. somewhat resembles it, but not correct.
```

[image]

Comment: Is `new_img` a `cv::Mat` object?  It is not clear from the actual code as this isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: sorry, yes it is, ill fix edit that

Comment: it is not a greyscale image, that might explain why. I tried earlier to account for multiple channels but i couldn't figure it out.

edit: also im fine if it outputs the greyscale image for now

Comment: Yes, that explains why. Let me modify my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have alluded to this being a **colour image**, this means that you have three slices of the matrix to consider.  Your code only considers one slice.  First off you need to make sure that you declare the right size of the image.  In MATLAB, the first dimension is **always the number of rows** while the second dimension is the number of columns.  Now you have to add the number of channels too on top of this.  I'm assuming this is an RGB image so there are three channels.

Therefore, change your `dims` to:

```
mwSize nd = 3;
mwSize dims[] = {H, W, nd};
```

Changing `nd` to 3 is important as this will allow you to create a 3D matrix.  You only have a 2D matrix.  Next, make sure that you are accessing the image pixels at the right location in the `cv::Mat` object.  The way you are accessing the image pixels in the nested pair of `for` loops assumes a **row-major** fashion (iterating over the columns first, then the rows).  As such, you need to interchange `i` and `j` as `i` accesses the rows and `j` accesses the columns. You will **also** need to access the channel of the colour image so you'll need another `for` loop to compensate.  For the grayscale case, you have properly compensated for the column-major memory configuration for the MATLAB MEX matrix though.  This is verified because `j` accesses the columns and you need to **skip over** by rows amount in order to access the next column.  However, to accommodate for a colour image, you must also skip over by `image.rows*image.cols` to go to the next layer of pixels.

Therefore your `for` loop should now be:

```
for (int k = 0; k < nd; k++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < H; i++) { 
        for (int j = 0; j < W; j++) {
            outMat[k*image.rows*image.cols + i + j*image.rows] = new_img.at<uchar>(i, j, k);
        }
    }
}
```

Take note that the container of pixels is most likely 8-bit unsigned character, and so you must change the template to `uchar` **not** `int`.  This may also explain why your program is crashing.

Comment: i added your changes and now matlab crashes =[

Comment: I made sure to change `nd = 3`... are you sure?

Comment: If it's a color image (probably of type `CV_8UC3`), shouldn't it be: `... = new_img.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[k];` ? at least `.at<uchar>(i,j,k);`

Comment: @Miki yes you're right. I'll change.  I didn't notice the `int` there... that's what you get for copying and pasting.

Comment: @rayryeng it compiles but it is still the same problem as before. The only reason i needed to output the image back to matlab was to compare between the output image and another, so I just did that within mex.

Thanks for the help however

Comment: @CharlesMarokhovsky no problem. Good luck.